# Serialize static attributes in Java

Tags: java, serialization

What happens if i'll try to serialize an attribute which is static?

thanks

Comment: What happens? I guess you'll end up finding out whether it works or not..

Comment: Your computer will explode, immediatly *fg* - no, it just gets serialized. Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [article](http://java.sys-con.com/node/36149):

> ### Tip 1: Handling Static Variables
>
> Java classes often hold some
>   globally relevant value in a static
>   class variable. We won't enter into
>   the long history of the debate over
>   the propriety of global variables -
>   let's just say that programmers
>   continue to find them useful and the
>   alternatives suggested by purists
>   aren't always practical.
>
> For static variables that are
>   initialized when declared,
>   serialization doesn't present any
>   special problems. The first time the
>   class is used, the variable in
>   question will be set to the correct
>   value.
>
> Some statics can't be initialized this
>   way. They may, for instance, be set by
>   a human during the running time of the
>   program. Let's say we have a static
>   variable that turns on debugging
>   output in a class. This variable can
>   be set on a server by sending it some
>   message, perhaps from a monitor
>   program. We'll also imagine that when
>   the server gets this message, the
>   operator wants debugging turned on in
>   all subsequent uses of the class in
>   the clients that are connected to that
>   server.
>
> The programmer is now faced with a
>   difficulty. When the class in question
>   arrives at the client, the static
>   variable's value doesn't come with it.
>   However, it contains the default
>   static state that's set when the
>   class's no-argument constructor is
>   called by `writeObject()`. How can the
>   client programs receive the new
>   correct value?
>
> The programmer could create another
>   message type and transmit that to the
>   client; however, this requires a
>   proliferation of message types,
>   marring the simplicity that the use of
>   serialization can achieve in
>   messaging. The solution we've come up
>   with is for the class that needs the
>   static transmitted to include a
>   "static transporter" inner class. This
>   class knows about all the static
>   variables in its outer class that must
>   be set. It contains a member variable
>   for each static variable that must be
>   serialized. StaticTransporter copies
>   the statics into its member variables
>   in the `writeObject()` method of the
>   class. The `readObject()` method
>   "unwraps" this bundle and transmits
>   the server's settings for the static
>   variables to the client. Since it's an
>   inner class, it'll be able to write to
>   the outer class's static variables,
>   regardless of the level of privacy
>   with which they were declared.

And from another [article](http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~amk/foo/advjava/notes/serial.html):

> ### Static or transient data
>
> However, this "ease" is not true in
>   all cases. As we shall see,
>   serialization is not so easily applied
>   to classes with static or transient
>   data members. Only data associated
>   with a specific instance of a class is
>   serialized, therefore static data,
>   that is, data associated with a class
>   as opposed to an instance, is not
>   serialized automatically. To serialize
>   data stored in a static variable one
>   must provide class-specific
>   serialization.
>
> Similarly, some classes may define
>   data members to use as scratch
>   variables. Serializing these data
>   members may be unnecessary. Some
>   examples of transient data include
>   runtime statistics or hash table
>   mapping references. These data should
>   be marked with the transient modifier
>   to avoid serialization. Transient, by
>   definition, is used to designate data
>   members that the programmer does not
>   want or need to be serialized. See
>   Java in a Nutshell, page 174: mouse
>   position, preferred size, file handles
>   (machine specific (native code)).
>
> When writing code if something is
>   declared transient, then this triggers
>   (to programmer) necessity of the
>   posibility of special code for
>   serialization later.
>
> To serialize an object, you create
>   some sort of OutputStream object and
>   then wrap it inside an
>   ObjectOutputStream object. At this
>   point you only need to call
>   `writeObject()` and your object is
>   magically serialized and sent to the
>   OutputStream. To reverse the process,
>   you wrap an InputStream inside an
>   ObjectInputStream and call
>   `readObject(`). What comes back is, as
>   usual, a handle to an upcast Object,
>   so you must downcast to set things
>   straight.  If you need to dynamically
>   query the type of the object, you can
>   use the getClass method. Specifically
>   `dk.getClass.getName()` returns the name
>   of the class that `dk` is an instance
>   of. I.e., this asks the object for the
>   name of its corresponding class
>   object. (Hmmm, True, but what about
>   syntax? I still need to know what it
>   is to declare it...too bad) (C++ can
>   do this in one operation (`dynamic_cast`
>   (gives null if wrong type)), java can
>   use `instanceof` operator to check if it
>   is what I think (see Core Java, Ch5
>   Inheritence, Casting section)

Comment: Stand back from the static variables.

Comment: Oh I totally agree. Static variables must be used with a lot of caution! But I was just answering the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can defnitely serialise the static variable, but we wont be able to get any purpose of serialisation on the static variables.
Why because the Static variables are not bounded to any objects in scope.
We serialize objects to store them so they can retrieved later for any use.

Only the Transient varibles you cant make them to get serialised.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the *value* of a static variable / attribute.  But strictly speaking, you don't serialize a variable or attribute in its own right, whether it is class level, instance level, or local to a method.

Normally the instance level attributes of an object are serialized *as part of* the parent object; i.e. the object that they are attributes of.  If you translate that to class level attributes, then the notional parent is the class.  While there is a runtime object that denotes this class (i.e. the `java.lang.Class` returned by `this.getClass()`), this object is not serializable.  So from that perspective, a class level (static) attribute is not serializable.